# Publishing ASP.NET MVC3 Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, publish

This is really confusing me, it just does not want to work. I did exactly like the walk-through on MSDN says and I still get Under Construction page everytime I browse to the domain (fisharwe.com). Ok enough with the nag, here's what I did:

In Visual Studio 2010, I right clicked the project name and chose Publish. I chose to publish to the File System and everything went okey. Then I used CuteFTP to upload the files to the httpdocs folder (Plesk control panel), the live support guy said this is supposed to be the public folder. Finally, I tried to open the site and still nothing shows up... All I get is:

> The site you are trying to view does
>   not currently have a default page. It
>   may be in the process of being
>   upgraded and configured.

So what's going on?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running? Looks like possibly IIS6? If so, [try this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Where can I find this? (P.S: this is the first time I deploy to a Windows server, I used to be a PHP guy...)

Comment: Nope. This was the case, but I requested an account migration to IIS7

Comment: @KassemYou sure the migration has finished already then? The headers look like IIs6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the following response header i'm seeing returned on your domain it seems your running IIS6;

```
Content-Length  1433
Content-Type    text/html
Content-Location    http://fisharwe.com/iisstart.htm
Last-Modified   Fri, 21 Feb 2003 18:48:30 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Etag    "0938ad3d9d9c21:2f56e6"
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Mon, 18 Apr 2011 18:04:19 GMT
```

Take a good look at [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) article by Phil Haacked, hope it's helpfull. He explains how to set up an mvc website on iis6

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the server to send all requests through ASP.Net.